# Need code for Beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Block Diagram]

For my presentation using `beamer` I need code for this image structure. can anyone help me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done with [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=0.9, transform shape,
  myblock/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=0.7cm,
    text width=1.3cm
  },
  arr/.style={
    ->,
    >=latex
  },
  node distance=0.5cm and 0.5cm 
]
% the blocks
\node[myblock]
  (A) {};
\node[myblock,right=of A]
  (B) {};
\node[myblock,above right=0.5cm and -10pt of B.north east]
  (C) {};
\node[myblock,below right=0.5cm and -10pt of B.south  east]
  (D) {};
\node[myblock,right=of C,minimum height=10pt]
  (E) {};
\node[myblock,right=of D,minimum height=10pt]
  (F) {};
\node[myblock,right=3cm of B]
  (G) {};
\node[myblock,right=of G,minimum height=1.3cm]
  (H) {};

% the arrows
\draw[arr]
  (A) -- (B);
\draw[arr]
  (B) |- (C);
\draw[arr]
  (B) |- (D);
\draw[arr]
  (C) -- (E);
\draw[arr]
  (D) -- (F);
\draw[arr]
  (E) -| (G);
\draw[arr]
  (F) -| (G);
\draw[arr]
  (G) -- (H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @GonzaloMedina can you please explain how did you achieve rectangle with draw? What about different shapes, say star ?